# How to correctly format raw ethernet frame?

Tags: c, ethernet

I am trying to send raw ethernet frames between two network devices by making calls directly to the network driver. I am working in OSE so I will skip how these calls look. I have successfully sent and received frames between the units but for some payloads the system crashes.

I am trying to send strings but the problem, however, when sending **some** of these strings the entire system crashes and I have to reboot.

The code below shows how the frame is constructed:

```
#define ETH_LEN 6
int sendBufLen = 1400;

/*Ethernet header*/
unsigned char dst_mac[6] = {0x00, 0x80, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11};
unsigned char src_mac[6] = {0x00, 0x80, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22};
unsigned char ether_type[2] = {0x08, 0x00}; //Ipv4 - does not really matter for this purpose

//1//char msg[] = "Nice med en .,stor delay och ett stort meddelande osv etc hejhopp mera text yaay012345678";
//2//char msg[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elitSed porta libero vitae viveruoopi";
//3//char msg[] = "Loce med en .,stor delay och ett stort meddelande osv etc hejhopp mera text yaay012345678";
//4//char msg[] = "Lorem med en .,stor delay och ett stort meddelande osv etc hejhopp mera text yaay012345678";
char msg[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elitSed porta libehejhopp mera text yaay012345678"; //5//

memset(sendbuf, 0, sendBufLen);
memcpy(sendbuf, dst_mac, ETH_LEN);            //Fill dst MAC
memcpy(sendbuf + ETH_LEN, src_mac, ETH_LEN);  //Fill src MAC
memcpy(sendbuf + 2 * ETH_LEN, ether_type, 2); //Fill eth type/length

memcpy(sendbuf + (2+ 2*ETH_LEN), msg, strlen(msg)); //Fill payload

//BIOScalls to the driver to send the buffer  OSE-specific
```

The preamble and CRC, the driver takes care of so that I could skip.

Now, only some of the messages above can be sent, for example message 5 which is active now crashes the card. However message 1,3 and 4 works without problem. Message 2 also crashes the card.

This has led me to believe that the ethernet frame is not correctly formated? However all the examples I have seen only fill a char buffer with:

- 6 bytes dst MAC
- 6 bytes src MAC
- 2 bytes type/length MAC
- x bytes payload

There is a field IEEE 802.1Q (optional) after the src MAC field with 4 bytes. As I understand the driver only assumes that this field is set if the field starts with 0x8100? This field will not be relevant since it is for VLAN. Is this correctly understood that I could ignore this field?

However, now to the real strange thing. If I set the first 4 bytes after the MAC-src field, i.e. to **0** . I can send all these messages! Is this just a coincidence, or is there anything with the IEEE 802.1Q field that I miss?

What I think is so strange with all of this is that the system crashes for some messages. Even if the frame was not correctly formated, should not the driver just forget about that message?

To summarize up my questions:

- How should the ethernet frame be formated?
- Can I ignore the IEEE 802.1Q field?
- Why does my system crash when some messages are fed into the network driver for send(write)?

Comment: *** ALERT!  DANGER! *** network code containing strlen() calls :)

Comment: @MartinJames Why? If he can guarantee it's nil terminated (and he can obviously), why would it be a problem?

Comment: Are you sure the ethertype doesn't matter? I wonder if it's possible the driver code is looking for the payload length from what it thinks is an IPv4 packet. What if you specify the payload length instead?

Comment: Yes that is true. One should be careful with strlen() in network code but that is not the problem here. This is just for test atm. 
@FatalError: Yes, that was my guess aswell but that does not work either (should have stated that in the question). Also I should say that I also supplied the length of the buffer when calling the network driver, so thats strange.

Comment: Where is sendbuf declared?  What are the lifetime constraints on it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed to include that. The buffer is declared as "char sendbuf[1400]". The sendbuf is declared at the top of the process and the process never terminates (ininite while loop) so the lifetime should not be an issue.